# How do I access the source code of a 3rd party style sheet loaded using a LINK tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm downloaded a stylesheet from another site and would like to access the source of the style sheet in my own page using javascript. I imagine the final solution will look something like the following, but with source_code replaced by the correct property.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link id="data_item_1" rel="StyleSheet" href="http://www.someothersite.com/styles.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>XSS proxy data pull test</p>
        <script language="javascript">
            di1 = document.getElementById('data_item_1');
            alert(di1.source_code);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this...you can access the styles themselves via [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.styleSheets), but you an't view the **raw** source this way...only access the rules.

There are some differences between what's there and the raw source:

- Formatting
- Rules/Selectors the browser doesn't understand will likely be discarded (this varies slightly per-browser)

If you could view the raw source, this would be a way to bypass the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)...so don't expect this to ever be allowed.